# Ruby-ish way to create record inside model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the ruby-ish way to do

```
model/subscription.rb
def subscription_create
       uri_json = JSON.parse(uri.to_s)
     sub = Subscription.new(ibm_response: uri_json)
end
```

other than putting it in controller.

What about **self.new** or **self.build** ?

Comment: Basically a third class which sits between  model and controller. Inside the controller you will create the object of the third class and then inside it you can call the model object. This is just a thought which depends on usecases..

Comment: @ArupRakshit  instead of Subscription.new ,i can use self.new or self.build. what about that  ?

Comment: The code you are showing doesn't make any sense. Rather you do it inside the controller. If controller becomes heavy or fat, extract those into a new class and then connect between each of them..

Comment: @ArupRakshit To make the controller light i want to move above code to controller. one way is to create a new class between M and C. i m looking for another way if possible

Comment: @ArupRakshit how about putting it in helper ?

Comment: helper is not for that stuff. Please follow rails MVC and then slowly learn how to extract stuff.. that way you can learn.